# C# - How do I use an array of arrays as input for "parameterized" method?

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, parameters

I want to create a method that accepts a "parameterized" input object of type string array of string array. Something like:

```
public void MyMethod(params string[][] input)
{
   //...do stuff
}
```

I am calling this method as follows:

```
MyMethod({"arry1-elem1","arry1-elem2"}, {"arry2-elem1","arry2-elem2"}, {"arry3-elem1","arry3-elem2"});
```

However, when I do this I get the following error:

> Invalid expression term '{'

What am I doing wrong here. Is it not possible to input an implicitly typed array as an input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
MyMethod(new string[]{"arry1-elem1","arry1-elem2"}, new string[]{"arry2-elem1","arry2-elem2"}, new string[]{"arry3-elem1","arry3-elem2"});
```

You aren't declaring their type when you're attempting to pass them in.

Comment: Also `string` is redundant. You could remove it. Just `new[]` is enough.

Comment: True, but I like it to be obvious at first glance what it is. If you prefer to leave it out feel free, just my preference ^^

Comment: Followup question, is there any way to forcibly limit the nested array of arrays to 2 dimensions? e.g.  `public void MyMethod(params string[][2] input)`

Comment: Not particularly, you could add validation inside the method to check and throw (probably an ArgumentException) if there are more or less, or you can create a class that can be instantiated with only two. Really your only two options.

Answer (score 2):

Even better, you don't have to say `string`:

```
MyMethod(new[]{"a","b"}, new[]{"c","d"});
```